# Using Umbracos Media Node 'Type' field to create download icons

Tags: file, download, umbraco

I have a data type called 'download'. Amongst the properties that make it up is a Media Picker to associate a file from the media library. I need to list these 'downloads' using razor and each file needs an icon to identify what file format it is.

Now I can create the list of 'downloads' and even create links to the files but I was wondering if Umbraco has a property that would allow me to show the correct file format icon. I noticed that when viewing a media item each has 'type' property. If I could get that output I could create a css class for each possibility. But how do I get to that property?

Answer (score 0):

Media Types are just like Document Types. Their properties are configured in the Settings section. If you take a look at the "File" or the "Image" Media Type, you can see what alias they use for the property. In this case the "Type" property has an alias of `umbracoExtension`. An example of how to access the property using Razor is as follows:

```
var file = Library.MediaById(1066);
@file.umbracoExtension
```

Based on the extension that is returned, you can add a class to the link to the download file by doing something like this:

```
int folderId = 1000;
var files = Library.MediaById(folderId);

<ul>
@foreach (var file in files)
{
    string attr = "";

    if (file.umbracoExtension != "")
    {
        attr = " class=\"" + file.umbracoExtension + "\"";
    }

    <li@attr><a href="@file.umbracoFile">@file.Name</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Then you can add the appropriate image icon via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

dludlow's answer is technically what you were asking for, but I wanted to post an alternative suggestion that you can do what you're asking in pure CSS3, without needing to do anything different in Razor.

Here's just a partial sample of something I grabbed to show what I mean:

```
#sample-div a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding-left:20px;
 line-height:18px;
}
#sample-div a[href$='.jpg'],
#sample-div a[href$='.jpeg'],
#sample-div a[href$='.gif'],
#sample-div a[href$='.psd'] {
 background:transparent url(/images/icon_image.png) center left no-repeat;
}
#sample-div a[href$='.csv'],
#sample-div a[href$='.xls'],
#sample-div a[href$='.xlsx'],
#sample-div a[href$='.xlw'] {
 background:transparent url(/images/icon_excel.png) center left no-repeat;
}
#sample-div a[href$='.pdf'] {
 background:transparent url(/images/icon_acrobat.png) center left no-repeat;
}
#sample-div a[href$='.ppt'],
#sample-div a[href$='.pps'] {
 background:transparent url(/images/icon_powerpoint.png) center left no-repeat;
}
#sample-div a[href$='.doc'],
#sample-div a[href$='.docx'],
#sample-div a[href$='.rtf'],
#sample-div a[href$='.txt'],
#sample-div a[href$='.wps'] {
 background:transparent url(/images/icon_word.png) center left no-repeat;
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to improve this, such as adding more extensions, using a spritemap instead of individual images (which I'd suggest), simplifying the `background` shorthand rule to just `background-image`, etc...

Best of luck to you!
Best of luck!